# How to supply jetson tx2 with dji matrice 100 battery?

Tags: power-supply, power, drone, battery, power-converter

I want to put my jetson tx2 dev kit on the drone but i don't know how to supply the jetson using drone's battery.

I think i need a dc/dc regulator (converter) cause the jetson require at most 19.6V, drone's battery delivers 22V.

Which converter could do the trick? My fear regards the consumption of the jetson dev kit (about 25W, not sure cause I read online) and the ampere needed to power up the TX2.

Comment: Your question title is a little misleading. As its worded, its a bit off-topic (asking how to...) since the body of your question is asking for a recommendation for hardware (on-topic). Could you provide more information on what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for a method to supply the jetson tx2 using the drone m100 battery. I suppose that i need a dc/dc converter, but i don't know which one because i need to be careful regarding ampere, volt and watt.